How to update telegram message once data from a request is received?
I've seen different telegram bots sending messages in which data is loading from an external source (eg: The first version of the message is "The current weather is :" and then there's a request made to receive the weather data and the telegram message updates in real time with the data that was received, so the final message is "The current weather is : cloudy".
In this case cloudy would be the data that was received after sending the first version of the message which was then seemlessly updated a few seconds later.
How can I reproduce that, is it simply the bot updating his message ? And is it possible with the telethon library for python because I can't seem to find anything related in the documentation (cf: https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/index.html)
